# Exception while trying to lazy loading entities with Karaf container

Tags: hibernate, jpa, transactions, karaf

I'm trying to load data from database using lazy loading method but an exception occurs, I'm using Karaf 3.0.0, Hibernate 4.2.2.Final and JPA 2.
I tried also to open a transaction before making the request but the problem persists:

```
EntityManager em = HibernateUtil.getEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
List<Position> list = taxiEntity.getPositionsList();
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
```

The exception is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: fr.pu.e
ntities.Toolbar.mainWindowList, could not initialize proxy - no Session
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwL
azyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTe
mporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:186)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initia
lize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:545)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(A
bstractPersistentCollection.java:124)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBa
g.java:266)
        at fr.actiasodielec.dsw802.toolbar.instantiator.MainToolbar.<init>(MainT
oolbar.java:54)
        at fr.actiasodielec.dsw802.mainwindow.MainWindowGui.initGUI(MainWindowGu
i.java:78)
        at fr.actiasodielec.dsw802.mainwindow.InitializationSW.process(Initializ
ationSW.java:112)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you fetch lazy collection outside of transaction (session).
You have 2 ways:

1. Eagerly fetch required collection ([link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#performance-fetching))
2. Set hibernate property (for SessionFactory):

   ```
   <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
   ```

Comment: Thank you a lot, the second solution worked for me <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true" />